# Adding Hindi Fonts to Ubuntu Font Family

Tags: fonts

I wish to add more Hindi fonts to the Ubuntu Font Library, so that I can use them in LibreOffice.

The three font types are available on this website in TTF format on this website.
http://www.abhivyakti-hindi.org/abhi/hindi_shusha_fonts_dl_help.htm

How do I add them?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First download fonts.

Then open Nautilus as root using the command: `gksudo nautilus`
or `sudo -H nautilus`

Now copy your font file to `/usr/share/fonts`.

You can also paste it in `/usr/share/fonts/truetype/ubuntu-font-family`

(Type  <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd>  to navigate quickly)

Now you can easily use those fonts In LibreOffice.

Comment: shusha.ttf did not allow to get copied on to, or pasted  through the above steps.

Answer (score 5):

You can install fonts from terminal:

```
sudo apt-get install fonts-indic
```

Answer (score 2):

Just go to the website you mentioned and click on the one you want.

[image: fonts]

Open it and click on install

[image: dialog for font installation]

and it will be installed. You can search for it in your LibreOffice Writer.